# UITableViewCell setSelected, but selection not shown

Tags: iphone, uitableview, selection

I want to keep a cell selected, and only change when I select another cell.
In tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: I have set a selected cell with [cell setSelected:YES].
I know the cell is selected, but it is not shown.
When I call [tableView reloadData] the selected cell flashes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should use `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` instead of the selected property for `UITableViewCell`

See sample [UICatalog](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/UICatalog/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007710) and read [UITableView reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:)

Comment: Your links are dead.